# what is the time complexity of this code and how? in Big-O

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

```
int i, j, k = 0;
for (i  = n/2; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2) {
        k = k + n/2;
    }
}
```

I came across this question and this is what I think.
The outer loop will run, N/2 times and the inner loop will run logN times so it should be N/2*logN. But this is not the correct answer.
The correct answer is O(NlogN), can anybody tell me what I am missing?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the time complexity of your code? in your opinion and why?

Comment: @AmiHollander The outer loop will run, N/2 times and the inner loop will run logN times so it should be N/2*logN. But this is not the correct answer.

Comment: Those who have downvoted my question, I would request you guys to please comment the reason so I can learn the right way of posting questions.

Comment: @ManishSundriyal then this would give O(n.log(n)). Why you say it is not the correct answer?

Comment: @ManishSundriyal you need to explain in the question, what is your opinion? ask how to solve a problem? and not ask for the answer, your commect could appear in the question and it would have been much better... why is not O(n log(n))?

Comment: @ManishSundriyal A good question would include something like "I think the answer is x, but my professor told me that y is the correct answer; so can you help me understand if s/he is right, and what I am missing?" I think editing your question to include this will have people upvote it to offset the downvotes. So what is the correct answer that is given to you? nlogn?

Comment: @AmiHollander thank you very much for pointing out that

Comment: @FatihAkici thank you too for explaining the right way

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It was O(n/2.log(n)) according to me. But now I have known why it is O(n.log(n)) and not what I was thinking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: @ManishSundriyal You're welcome. (n/a)*log(n)+b is nlog(n), because those constants are always omitted per the mathematical definition of big-O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at this block of code.

First of all, you can notice that inner loop doesn't depend on the external, so the complexity of it would not change at any iteration.

```
for (j = 2; j <= n; j = j * 2) {
    k = k + n/2;
}
```

I think, your knowledge will be enough to understand, that complexity of this loop is *O(log n)*.

Now we need to understand how many times this loop will be performed. So we should take a look at external loop

```
for (i  = n/2; i <= n; i++) {
```

and find out, that there will be *n / 2* iterations, or *O(n)* in a Big-O notation.

Combine these complexities and you'll see, that your *O(log n)* loop will be performed *O(n)* times, so the total complexity will be *O(n) * O(log n) = O(n log n)*.